# Set a picture/tikz in the chapter background book \titleformat

Tags: chapters, backgrounds

i want to use different tikz pictures or *.img-files in the chapterpages background. Documentclass is the twoside book.

So far i did the newcommand to get different \titleformats like:

```
\newcommand{\intro}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\thechapter ##1}
}

\newcommand{\implementation}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\thechapter ##1}
}
```

now i want to set an image or tikz-picture in the **background**, that didnt affect the position of the pagenumber and name or the following text. But i can't find the position where to add it. Tried to set it to the different titleformat parameters. but they all affect the positioning of the pagenumber and name.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\intro}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\itshape }
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorbox{gray!30}{\rlap{\raisebox{20pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter}}}\parbox[c][40pt][c]{\linewidth}{\Large\scshape\centering##1}}}
  %here an example tikz arrow that i want in the background
  [{\begin{tikzpicture} \draw [->,ultra thick] (0,-5) -- (10,5); \end{tikzpicture}}]
}


\begin{document}

\intro
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could have a look at the `background` package.

Comment: try to change `\begin{tikzpicture}` by  `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]`